# Masculine and Feminine Potencies

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, gender, bon

In several places–for example, in texts around the [Nine Purification Breaths](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/nine-purification-breaths-and-channels-in-genderqueer-and-intersex-individuals)–I've seen references to either masculine or feminine "obstacles linked with potencies" that are described as being "masculine" or "feminine."

What are the obscurations and "obstacles linked with potencies" that are "masculine" or "feminine" and what are their characteristics?

Answer (score 1):

This article on wikipedia discusses some of the kleshas or poisons
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleshas_(Buddhism)#Two_obscurations

Some of them appear to be feminine (emotional) and some masculine (intellectual)

Two obscurations[edit]
Mahayana literature often features an enumeration of "two obscurations" (Wylie: sgrib gnyis), the "obscuration of conflicting emotions" (Sanskrit: kleśa-avaraṇa, Wylie: nyon-mongs-pa'i sgrib-ma) and the "obscuration concerning the knowable" (Sanskrit: jñeya-avaraṇa, Wylie: shes-bya'i sgrib-ma).[19]